# Initialization of weights in IRLS (Iteratively reweighted least squares)

Tags: irls

How to initialize weights in IRLS?

On the [wikipedia page about IRLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares) it is stated that:

> $W^{(t)}$ is the diagonal matrix of weights, usually with all elements set initially to: $w^{(0)}_i = 1$

but without any direct reference to the source of this information.
Why is this the "usual" way of initializing the weights? Are there other ways to do it that might offer any advantages?

Answer (score -1):

In the absence of a prior about the weights, it is natural to democratically specify "equal believability to all readings" . If there is evidence of a statistically significant departure from this assumption by finding error variances that demonstrably change over different time periods then we are motivated to alter the weights. I can think of no other way other than in a delphi-type approach obtain prior estimates of these varying degrees of belief..

Comment: It is hard to see how this is pertinent to the question: IRLS is not about degrees of belief, nor will altering the initial weights make much difference in general, because IRLS is a procedure that *finds* appropriate weights to accomplish a robust regression.

Comment: IRLS is all about degrees of belief as it weights(believes) each value , possibly differently. Weighted least squares essentially uses different (weights) to reflect possible heterogeneity in the error variance.

Comment: Could you provide a reference for that?  I have encountered IRLS only in the context of [robust regression and smoothing techniques,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares) where "degrees of belief" was never a consideration.

Comment: forget the word degree of belief just replace it  with weights . http://docplayer.net/12080848-Outliers-level-shifts-and-variance-changes-in-time-series.html is a reference for identifying weights (transformations)

Comment: I'm sorry; I cannot see the point or sense in undertaking a "delphi-type approach" in order merely to *initialize* weights that will be changed by the IRLS algorithm anyway!  Are you sure you have the same understanding of "IRLS" as the rest of us (as evidenced in our links to the Wikipedia article)?

Comment: u r right there is no need for a delphi appraoch as IRLS automatically determnined.

Comment: @IrishStat in view of your concessions what value is there left in your answer?

Comment: If IRLS can be used with nonlinear modelling then the delphi approach to pre-guessing the starting weights would be unnecessary. I don't know enough about IRLS to make that assessment.